# Converting KML coordinates to Leaflet

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, kml, csv, latitude-longitude

I am trying to convert a Google Map KML file to a csv, to map the longitude and latitude points on Leaflet. But the coordinates keep mis-projecting and some end up off the land mass.

The steps I have done are:
- Download KML file
- Import into a GIS package (both MapInfo 12 and QGIS), and used the projections of WGS84 EPSG 3857, WGS84 EPSG 4326 and Google Mercator EPSG 900913, to create long/lat points
- Save this table as csv
- Upload to Leaflet using the Recline.js in DKAN to allow users to preview the map data.

Screenshot 1 is the original google map, and then screenshot 2 is the csv on Leaflet

[image] [image]

Have looked around the rest of the forum and cannot find an answer. Any help?

Comment: which of the the projections of WGS84 EPSG 3857, WGS84 EPSG 4326 and Google Mercator EPSG 900913 did you use?

Comment: Any reason why not directly importing the KML into Leaflet, using plugins like [leaflet-omnivore](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore) or [Leaflet.FileLayer](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.FileLayer)?

Comment: Thanks @iant
we tried this a few times and used all 3, WGS84 EPSG 3857 initially and then tried the other 2. 
WGS84 EPSG 3857: We just extracted the raw lat/long from the kml file and used them in leaflet
WGS84 EPSG 4326 and Google Mercator EPSG 90091: We used the MapInfo and QGIS coordinate extraction tools to change the projection to WGS84 EPSG 4326 and Google Mercator EPSG 90091. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @ghybs
Not really, except we're relataive newbies to this and was hoping of developing a simple methodology for some users to transfer their data from kml to Leaflet in DKAN with lat/long. Use of plugins, to be honest think we'd struggle at this stagea, may be a tech step too far for us. Something to definitely follow up though.

Comment: the original KML should be in 4326 (otherwise it's not really KML) so that may be where the issue occurs

Comment: Thanks @iant. Have checked and it is. The KML imports and displays fine in QGIS/MapInfo, the issue is in the transformation of the data to csv with lat/long.

Comment: @Cambs.Insight just give it a try with the Leaflet.FileLayer [online demo](http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.FileLayer/) and see if you can achieve the desired result. If satisfied, all instructions to install the plugin should be described on the GitHub page, and should be relatively easy.

Comment: Thanks @ghybs although this plugin does work with the kml file, we are using a dkan upload portal which doesn't accept kml files. We want to maintain this default upload process to minimise confusion for new and existing users. 

Is there a way of exporting the coordinates (into csv) from the kml and uploading them to leaflet without mis-projecting them and without any plugins? thank you again for your previous suggestions.

Comment: @Cambs.Insight for sure there is a way, you should be able to find utilities on the Web to do the extraction for you. Another possibility would be… to let your user import the KML directly into Leaflet (most plugins do the process on client side), then export into GeoJSON or convert to CSV / whatever, so that you can upload to your server… Infinite possibilities, depending on your programming skills.

Comment: Hi. 
Thank you for your inputs, we have still been working on this issue, and have found that the problem is actually that Leaflet is not reading the negative longitude values correctly. Something which is a lot simpler! 

Instead, Leaflet plots the points as if the longitude was actually a positive number. This is not great, seeing as the Meridian line goes through the centre of Cambridgeshire.

Is leaflet just misinterpreting the - sign? If so how do we fix this? Or is it something else?

Comment: You have to use **WGS84 EPSG 4326**